# Sending data to WebAPI using WebClient.UploadString causes server error for larger values of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I am creating a tool for uploading csv output files to be processed into a database.  For various reasons we are automating this via powershell, and the easiest route was to create our own `Cmdlet` sets.  This has worked really well with our smaller data sets but isn't working so hot with our larger data sets.

We have a requirement to be cross-domain when sending our data, as we can't guarantee all our machines are on the same domain, or even in a domain.  Early on, this meant we went with `WebClient` since we had access to `System.Net.NetworkCredential` through it.

Format for the PS client code is straightforward:

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json for serializing

// ResPack resultsPackage is just a container class with some info
//   plus one or more log files read in earlier

var postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultsPackage)
response = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(_uri, postBody);
```

I am using WebApi2 in an IIS8.5 (local via Win 8.1) environment to accept these files as POST and am keeping it really simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ResultsPackageResponse> Post()
{
    dynamic contentJson = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultsPackageInfo>(contentJson) as ResultsPackageInfo;

    var response = new ResultsPackageResponse();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.ClassicLogData))
    {
        var dataClassic = DeserializeClassicLogWithMap<ClassicLog, ClassicLogMap>(content.ClassicLogData);
        response.ClassicLogResultId = ImportClassicResultsToDb(dataClassic, content.ReportSetup);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.NewLogData))
    {
        var dataNewLog = DeserializeNewLogWithMap<ClassicLog, ClassicLogMap>(content.NewLogData);
        response.NewLogResultId = ImportNewResultsToDb(dataNewLog, content.ReportSetup);
    }
    return response;
}
```

The `WebApiConfig.cs` is set up to use a `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`, because of some other tool interactions.

This works fine for smaller `postBody` sizes (files serialized were about 34k) but we start processing another type of log file that started throwing `webResponse.StatusCode` of Internal Server Error 500 (this is about 140k-800k).  Realistically these aren't that large of files, so I was surprised to get errors with larger files.

I have already checked the data itself, it is valid and formatted correctly.

I have looked online for size limitations and although this doesn't sound like it meets all the problems, I have implemented these changes to my `Web.Config`:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="240000" maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value ="1073741824"/>
</appSettings>
```

Nothing seems to have changed this behavior.

**Resolution**

I am using a formatter and this changes the game a little: `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`

I added this line in its constructor:

```
MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
```

And I added this to the web.config

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1073741824" />
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Did you debug to see if the request is even reaching your code?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Yes.  Running in debugger I can see it isn't hitting the WebApi controller.  I hit it fine with the smaller files, so I think it is a configuration issue... I just don't know where.

Comment: There is a max JSON length, and I'm doubtful it's the problem, but maybe try setting it

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Good idea, set that in `Web.Config` as well as setting the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` in WebApiConfig to `MaxDepth = int.MaxValue`.  Still no love though.  It has to be configuration, Traces show error code 500 but it just never reaches the webapi method.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Actually... that JSON Length was the problem... set it up as well as the maxdepth you said.  Rebooted (not just restart) and this is working now.  Thanks for ending a VERY long troubleshooting session.  Put that in an answer with a ref link and I will certainly mark this finished.